# NSPredicate for multiple matches in NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

First off: sorry if the title isn't very clear, I couldn't quite put my question into short words!

Please consider the following scenario:
- You are using Core Data for storing objects
- You want to fetch objects from your context
- You want to include a predicate to only fetch objects with certain properties
- You have an NSDictionary containing key-value pairs where the key represents the property name and the value represents the desired value to match against

**How is best to achieve this?**

I currently have the following, which is a quick and probably inefficient way of achieving this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil] forKeys: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"attr1", @"attr2", nil] ];

// Build predicate format
NSString *predicate = @"";
NSMutableArray *predicateArguments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int index = 0;
for (NSString *key in attributes) {
    NSString *value = [attributes objectForKey: key];
    predicate = [predicate stringByAppendingFormat: @"(%@ = %@) %@", key, @"%@", index == [attributes count]-1 ? @"" : @"AND "];
    [predicateArguments addObject: value];
    index++;
}

NSPredicate *matchAttributes = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate argumentArray:predicateArguments];
```

--

**Is there a shorter or more efficient way of achieving this predicate?**

Please be aware that block predicates are not an option due to not being supported with NSFetchRequest (Core Data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly shorter and perhaps more elegant way is to use a `NSCompoundPredicate`:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil] forKeys: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"attr1", @"attr2", nil] ];

// Build array of sub-predicates:
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in attributes) {
    NSString *value = [attributes objectForKey: key];
    [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value]];
}
// Combine all sub-predicates with AND:
NSPredicate *matchAttributes = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

**ADDED:** Even better (thanks to Paul.s):

```
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[attributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
    [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value]];
}];
NSPredicate *matchAttributes = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

Comment: You could make this slightly (1 line) shorter and most likely more efficient using block numeration `[attributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
      [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value]];
    }];`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions guys, very helpful. I copied Paul.s comment into the answer for future viewers incase they miss the comment!